# Calculate the relative path of a file in java

Tags: java, file

http://www.raykor.com/prob2solve.aspx  here is the link to the question.i have created directories and files that are required. I may have not understood the question properly but so far i have tried my best. Could try to read and understand the question and give a hint to solve the same.

Comment: Please describe the relevant parts of the "question" here. Also show what you have done and where exactly you fail.

Answer (score 5):

It isn't very clear what your quesiton is, but based on the title, the best way to determine the relative path of a file in Java is to use the `Path relativize(Path other)` method described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#relativize(java.nio.file.Path)).

As an example, here's how it could be used to solve the first problem on that site:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.*;

public void printFilesInPath(Path start) throws IOException {
    Files.walk(start)
         .filter(path -> path.toFile().isFile())
         .forEach(path -> System.out.println(start.relativize(path)));
}
```

Comment: A badly worded question, but you made a good effort of answering based on title.